# How can the size of a .blend file be reduced?

Tags: blend-files

I noticed that a .blend containing a single material downloaded from [Open Material Repository](http://matrep.parastudios.de/index.php) has only 63KB.

The default scene saved with compression already uses 447KB of disk space. How can files with less than 100KB be created?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an option when you save a .blend file, to compress it (uses a basic zip compression iirc).

There’s also an option to always do that by default, in user preferences, `File` tab, `Save & Load` section.

Comment: Thanks, seems that I failed to reload the file manager windows while testing.

Comment: I'm confused.. stacker, didn't you say you had tested with compression? Why is this accepted then? (What am I missing?)

Comment: @gandalf3 I tested this again and the file size had heavily reduced, so I assume that the files from material repository are compressed and the only issue was (embarrasing enough) that I failed to reload the current view of the OS filemanager (this time win7).Do you have any pointers that it could be something different?

Comment: @stacker Ah, I see. No, I had recently been trying to figure out what was making a certain .blend take up so much space, and so this question caught my interest :)